# python curses while loop and timeout

Tags: python, while-loop, timeout, curses

I am having a hard time understanding the window.timeout() function. To be more specific, I am toying with a "snake" game in python:

```
s = curses.initscr()
curses.curs_set(0)
w = curses.newwin()
w.timeout(100)

while True:
    move snake until it hits the wall
```

I understand that in this case, timeout(100) determines how fast the snake "moves", i.e. printing out new characters on the screen. However, I got stuck when I want to amend the code so that it waits until someone press "start". I wrote something like:

```
w.timeout(100)

while True:
    if w.getch() is not start: 
        stay at the initial screen
    else:
        while True:
            move the snake until it hits the wall
```

However, in this case, the timeout(100) seems to govern how long each time the program waits for w.getch(), not how long to wait between each time the snake moves. Also, I notice that in the first example, the timeout is declared at the top, outside the while loop. This looks weird to me because normally if I want to pause a while loop, I would put sleep() at the bottom inside the while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pause between snake moves, you could use `napms` to wait a given number of milliseconds (and unlike `sleep`, does not interfere with screen updates).  Setting `w.timeout` to 100 (milliseconds) is probably too long.  If you're not concerned with reading function-keys, you could use `nodelay` to set the `w.getch` to non-blocking, relying on the `napms` to slow down the loop.

Regarding the followup comment: in ncurses, the [`wtimeout`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/ncurses/tinfo/lib_options.c) function sets a property of the window named **`_delay`**, which acts within the [`getch` function](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/ncurses/base/lib_getch.c#L470), ultimately [passed to a timed-wait function](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/ncurses/base/lib_getch.c#L165) that would return early if there's data to be read.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use napms. But conceptually, when exactly does the program stop 100ms in the code? First I thought it stops after the entire program is run, but in the second example, it appears that it stops at the first while loop level (between each getch()), but not the second level (between each snake move).

Comment: On a related question, the solution of napms seems to have an undesired consequence: if i press "left right up down" fast enough (faster than the napms delay) multiple times, it will keep on moving after i stopped typing because it hasn't finished executing all the direction inputs. Is there a way I can implement something like min(napms(delay), next key_input)? Thanks!

Comment: I think [flushinp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.flushinp) is what you're looking for, but [typeahead](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.typeahead) helps too.